# fullcalendar 'refetchEvents' doesn't send new data request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, request, fullcalendar

This is the code: https://output.jsbin.com/puhisefido/
When I change the selection of "eventSelect" select, it always sends this post request:

```
POST: http://example.com/events.php
end: 2017-02-25
start: 2017-02-20
state: all
```

Why doesn't the "state" variable change its value?

Comment: Resolved, thanks to @arshaw:  
_because your data is only evaluated once in your code, at initial run. it's a JS fundamental.

you can make it dynamic:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/
see "Dynamic data parameter"_

Answer (score 0):

Try with replacing the eventSelect in the data with $( "#eventSelect" ).val();

Comment: It not works. It always sends "state: all" in the ajax request.